# Entering iOS application from push-notification without passcode

Tags: ios

Is there a way to open your iOS application from push-notification without entering passcode?

Comment: If it is possible, then the passcode will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so. The point of the pass code is to stop someone getting into your phone, why would that be disabled if you get a push notification ?

That would give someone access to your phone whenever you receive a push notification from an app or emails etc. There would be no point in having it then

Comment: Let's presume for a moment that this is a VOIP application :). And we want to answer a call and after answering phone can be locked again.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to control that. And if there was some hack I would assume apple would refuse it on the basis of allowing a thrid party app control its security measures. Also push notifications are NOT guaranteed to be delivered so it would be a bad design to have it rely on that as you would have know way of knowing if they got it